# foobar.withgoogle.com task Please Pass the Coded Messages java Test 4 fail

Tags: java

I'm working on foobar.withgoogle task "Please Pass the Coded Messages". I got correct calculations on my computer for every possible number but foobar prints

> Test 4 failed [Hidden]

Not sure where to go from here. Tried multiple inputs including ones with only 0 in it, negative numbers, more than 9 digits. All of which result in failing test 4.

Visible test cases all pass.

Does anyone have any ideas? No need to tell me the exact solution, just point me in the right direction please.

Thank you in advance.

Problem:

> You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function solution(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the solution. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits. The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

See below for code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {

/*To achieve the goal the program follows the below logic:
 * 1. sort the array with built in sort method
 * 2. Reverse the sorted array so we get the largest number possible
 * 3. Check if the number is divisible by 3 by adding together the individual digits
 * and checking if it is divisible by 3. If yes, generate a string from the array, 
 * convert it into an int and return the result.
 * 4. If the initial number is not divisible by 3, starting with the smallest number 
 * (right to left), so we are checking the largest number possible, we remove a digit until
 * we get to the first (largest) digit, checking if the sum of the remaining digits is 
 * divisible by 3. If so, the number is returned.
 * 5. If we iterated through the array and no solution was found, return 0.
 * 
*/
public static int solution (int[] l) {
    if(l.length==0) {return 0;}
    if(hasNegativeValue(l)){return 0;}
    if(l.length==1&&l[0]%3==0) {return l[0];}
    if(l.length==1&&l[0]%3!=0) {return 0;}
    Arrays.sort(l); // sort the array in ascending order
    l=reverseArray(l);
    int elementToRemove = l.length-1;
    if(sumArray(l)%3==0) {
        return Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(l).replaceAll("[^0-9]+",""));
    }else {
        while(elementToRemove>=0) {
            int[] testArray = removeElement(l,elementToRemove);
            if(sumArray(testArray)%3==0) {
                return Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(testArray).replaceAll("[^0-9]+",""));
            }
            elementToRemove--;
        }
        if(elementToRemove==0) {return 0;}else {return 0;}
    }
}

// Method to reverse  the array
public static int[] reverseArray(int[] arrayToReverse){
    if(arrayToReverse.length==1) {return arrayToReverse;}
    else {          
        int[] reversedArray=new int[arrayToReverse.length];
        int j=arrayToReverse.length;
        for (int i=0;i<arrayToReverse.length;i++) {
            reversedArray[j-1]=arrayToReverse[i];
            j--;
        }
        return reversedArray;
    }
}

//Method to sum all elements of the array
public static int sumArray(int[] arrayToSum) {
    if(arrayToSum.length==1) {return arrayToSum[0];}
    else {
        int result=0;
        for (int i=0;i<arrayToSum.length;i++) {
            result+=arrayToSum[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}

//Method to remove a specific element of an array
public static int[] removeElement(int [] initialArray,int index) {
    if(index<0||index>initialArray.length-1) {return initialArray;}
    else {
        int [] result = new int[initialArray.length-1];
        int j=0;
        for (int i=0;i<initialArray.length;i++) {
            if(i!=index) {
                result[j]=initialArray[i];
                j++;
            }else {continue;}
        }
        return result;
    }
}

//Method to check for negative element of an array
public static boolean hasNegativeValue(int[] i) {
    boolean isNegative=false;
    for(int number : i) {
        if(number<0) { isNegative=true;}
    }
    return isNegative;
}
}
```

Comment: [A digit is not a number](https://isequalto.com/iet-app/ask-the-world/SSwz0315-What-is-the-difference-between-number-and-digit?). Your list cannot contain negative numbers. No need to check for them.

Comment: Does this help? [foobar please-pass-the-coded-messages hidden test case not passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382333/foobar-please-pass-the-coded-messages-hidden-test-case-not-passing)

Answer (score 0):

I was solving the same FooBar problem and was facing the same issue. Then I realized you have to consider a case where you have to remove 2 digits at a time.
For Example: {9,6,3,1,1} or {3,3,4,4}
In these examples, if you remove 1 digit then you won't get a number which is divisible by 3. But if you remove 2 digits i.e. 963 or 33 are divisible by 3.
I got the approach but I am not sure how to code this.